# How does Sencha Touch matcher work?

Tags: regex, sencha-touch, matcher

I am trying to create a simple matcher that matches any string consisting of alphanumeric characters. I tried the following:

```
    Ext.regModel('RegistrationData', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'nickname',type: 'string'},
        ],

        validations: [
            {type: 'format', name: 'nickname', matcher: /[a-zA-Z0-9]*/}
        ]
    });
```

However this does not work as expected. I did not find any documentation on how should a regular expression in a matcher look like.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What are you expecting? And what's happening? Please provide an example so that we can check what may be wrong.

Comment: I expect that my matcher will match all nicknames that consist only of alphanumeric characters. That is nicknames Joe, Joe24, jOe28 should be matched. Nicknames like Joe#2, J/o/e, *89Joe should not be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a blog on [sencha.com](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-validations-and-associations-in-sencha-touch/), where they explain the validation.

I have no idea what sencha-touch is, but maybe it helps, when you tell us what you are giving to your regex, what you expect it to do, and what it actually does (does not work as expected is a bit vague). According to the blog it accepts "regular expression format", so for your simple check, it should be pretty standard.

**EDIT:**

As a wild guess, maybe you want to use anchors to ensure that the name has really only letters and numbers:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

`^` is matching the start of the string

`$` is matching the end of the string

Comment: @Palo You are welcome, another thing is probably you want to replace the `*` with a `+` otherwise it will accept an empty string, because `*` means 0 or more.

Comment: I actually want this to match even an empty string. I treat the empty string with another validator which has assigned a specific client message. So I will kepp * ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex `/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/` would match a string containing zero or more occurrences of lower or upper case characters (A-Z) or numbers anywhere in the string. That's why `Joe#2`, `J/o/e`, `*89Joe` as well as `Joe`, Joe24`and`jOe28` match - they all contain zero or more subsequent occurrences of the respective characters.

If you want your string to contain only the respective characters you have to change the regex according to [stema's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564757/how-does-sencha-touch-matcher-work/5565006#5565006):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

But this has still one problem. Due to the `*` which meas *zero or more occurrences* it also matches an empty string, so the correct string should be:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

with `+` meaning *one or more occurrences*. This will allow nicknames containing only one lowercase or uppercase character or number, such as `a`, `F` or `6`.

Comment: Thank you, I actually want this to match even an empty string ;)